SwiftCSV: "No exact matches in call to subscript" error when accessing CSV columns by name
I'm trying to load data from a CSV file using the SwiftCSV library in Swift. Here's my code:
import Foundation
import SwiftCSV
import SwiftUI

struct Question: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let questionText: String
    let options: [String]
    let correctAnswer: String
    let explanation: String
}

// Function to load questions from CSV
func loadQuestions(from csvFileName: String) -> [Question] {
    var questions = [Question]()
    
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: csvFileName, ofType: "csv") {
        do {
            let csv = try CSV<Enumerated>(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            for row in csv.rows {
                if let questionText = row[column: "question"],
                   let optionA = row[column: "optionA"],
                   let optionB = row[column: "optionB"],
                   let optionC = row[column: "optionC"],
                   let optionD = row[column: "optionD"],
                   let correctAnswer = row[column: "correctAnswer"],
                   let explanation = row[column: "explanation"] {
                    let question = Question(
                        questionText: questionText,
                        options: [optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD],
                        correctAnswer: correctAnswer,
                        explanation: explanation
                    )
                    questions.append(question)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error reading CSV file")
        }
    }
    
    return questions
}

However, I'm getting the following error at the line:
if let questionText = row[column: "question"],
until
let explanation = row[column: "explanation"] {
Error:
No exact matches in call to subscript
Here's a snippet of my CSV file:
"question","optionA","optionB","optionC","optionD","correctAnswer","explanation" "Marvel movies often feature strong teamwork, and the heroes must work ____ to defeat their enemies.","together","against","alone","separately","together","The correct word is 'together,' as teamwork involves collaboration."
I'm using SwiftCSV to parse the CSV file, and I need to access the columns by their header names. How can I fix this error and correctly access the CSV columns by name?

You should link to the SwiftCSV library you're using to make sure everyone is looking at the right one. Assuming it's the one I found, I think you need Named rather than Enumerated, and get rid of the column: label.
